# Weak event + lambda = memory leakage?

Tags: c#, wpf, lambda, garbage-collection

Playing with weak event

```
public class Test
{
    public Test(Button button)
    {
        WeakEventManager<Button, RoutedEventArgs>.AddHandler(button, nameof(Button.Click),
            (s, e) => MessageBox.Show("Tada"));
    }
}
```

with this code

```
Test _test;
void ButtonCreate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => _test = new Test(button);
void ButtonDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => _test = null;
void ButtonGC_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    GC.Collect(2);
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}
```

It looks like this event handler life time is longer than I'd expect.

Here is a demo where I click <kbd>Create</kbd> 3 times, then <kbd>Delete</kbd> and <kbd>GC</kbd>, but clicking the button will still execute all event handlers:

[image]

My question is what is wrong here?

---

Without lambda there is no such issue

```
public class Test
{
    public Test(Button button)
    {
        WeakEventManager<Button, RoutedEventArgs>.AddHandler(button,
            nameof(Button.Click), Button_Click);
    }
    void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => MessageBox.Show("Tada");
}
```

but [another problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43890059/1997232) arise, where event handler is still called after <kbd>Delete</kbd> unless <kbd>GC</kbd> is pressed!

Comment: Are you expecting setting `_test` to `null` to remove the event handler?

Comment: @stuartd, don't forget `GC.Collect()`. I expect object to be garbage collected and then event handler shouldn't be called. Am I wrong?

Comment: The point of a weak event is to prevent an event subscription from keeping the event source alive.  Add a finalizer to Test, like ~Test() => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("the end"); and you'll see the Test instances expire when you call GC.Collect().  The lambda doesn't need the Test instance to do its job and the button is alive throughout the test so you are not actually testing the usefulness of a weak event.

Comment: @HansPassant, I've added finalizer and I see it runs after `GC.Collect()`, but the event handler is still **when using lambda**, therefore my new question.. I didn't though what using weak event will have such effect, where "ready to be disposed" object (no references) required explicit garbage collection, otherwise event handler keeps running, but that's [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43890059/1997232). Here, I'd like only to understand what is wrong when using lambda.